# How can I count the number of rows that are not zero in a certain range in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Series that consists of numbers either 0 or 1.

```
2016-01-01    0
2016-01-02    1
2016-01-03    1
2016-01-04    0
2016-01-05    1
2016-01-06    1
2016-01-08    1
...
```

I want to make a dataframe using this Series, adding another series that provides information on how many 1s exist for a certain period of time.

For example, if the period was 5 days, then the dataframe would look like

```
              Value   1s_for_the_last_5days
2016-01-01    0
2016-01-02    1
2016-01-03    1
2016-01-04    0
2016-01-05    1       3
2016-01-06    1       4
2016-01-08    1       4
...
```

In addition, I'd like to know if I can count the number of rows that are not zero, in a certain range, in a situation like the below.

```
              Value   Not_0_rows_for_the_last_5days
2016-01-01    0
2016-01-02    1.1
2016-01-03    0.4
2016-01-04    0
2016-01-05    0.6       3
2016-01-06    0.2       4
2016-01-08    10        4
```

Thank you for reading this. I would appreciate it if you could give me any solutions or hints on the problem.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure where I should start. I can make it possible in excel by COUNTIF(OFFSET(G19,0,0,-5,1),">0"). But I wonder if there's a similar function in Python, corresponding to countif function in excel.

Comment: Read the line, split by space check whether value is 0 or 1?

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I think, spliting by space is the problem I'm dealing with. Do you happen to know any accociated functions for it?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+split+line+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=VX_XWKCAOYbb8Aex-77IDw

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I think there's some misunderstanding. My goal is to count the number of 1s in a certain range of the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) for this which creates a sized *window* and iterates over your given column while applying an aggregation like sum.

First create some dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ser = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=10), 
                index=pd.date_range("2016-01-01", periods=10),
                name="Value")
print(ser)

2016-01-01    1
2016-01-02    0
2016-01-03    0
2016-01-04    0
2016-01-05    0
2016-01-06    0
2016-01-07    0
2016-01-08    0
2016-01-09    1
2016-01-10    0
Freq: D, Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Now, use rolling:

```
summed = ser.rolling(5).sum()
print(summed)

2016-01-01    NaN
2016-01-02    NaN
2016-01-03    NaN
2016-01-04    NaN
2016-01-05    1.0
2016-01-06    0.0
2016-01-07    0.0
2016-01-08    0.0
2016-01-09    1.0
2016-01-10    1.0
Freq: D, Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Finally, create the resulting data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Value": ser, "Summed": summed})
print(df)

            Summed  Value
2016-01-01     NaN      1
2016-01-02     NaN      0
2016-01-03     NaN      0
2016-01-04     NaN      0
2016-01-05     1.0      0
2016-01-06     0.0      0
2016-01-07     0.0      0
2016-01-08     0.0      0
2016-01-09     1.0      1
2016-01-10     1.0      0
```

In order to count arbitrary values, define your own aggregation function in conjunction with `apply` on the rolling window like:

```
# dummy function to count zeros
count_func = lambda x: (x==0).sum()

summed = ser.rolling(5).apply(count_func)
print(summed)
```

You may replace `0` with any value or combination of values of your original series.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! May I ask you another question? What if they are not 1s, but real numbers like 1.2, 0.3, 0.5 and I want to count the number of real numbers in the column, in a certain range?

Comment: @maynull, you can use a mask `(df['Value'] > 0)` instead of `df['Value']`. `(df['Value'] > 0).rolling(5).sum()` should do the trick.

Comment: @maynull Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, pansen! I appreciate your help, Alex Fung! I hope you two have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 2):

`pd.Series.rolling` is a useful method but you can do this with a pythonic way:

```
def rolling_count(l,rolling_num=5,include_same_day=True):
    output_list = []
    for index,_ in enumerate(l):
        start = index - rolling_num - int(include_same_day)
        end = index + int(include_same_day)
        if start < 0:
            start = 0
        output_list.append(sum(l[start:end]))
    return output_list

data = {'Value': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        'date': ['2016-01-01','2016-01-02','2016-01-03','2016-01-04','2016-01-05','2016-01-06','2016-01-08']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('date')

l = df['Value'].tolist()

df['1s_for_the_last_5days'] = rolling_count(df['Value'],rolling_num=5)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
            Value  1s_for_the_last_5days
date                                    
2016-01-01      0                      0
2016-01-02      1                      1
2016-01-03      1                      2
2016-01-04      0                      2
2016-01-05      1                      3
2016-01-06      1                      4
2016-01-08      1                      5
```

Answer (score 1):

you want [rolling](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html)

```
s.rolling('5D').sum()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': s, '1s_for_the_last_5days': s.rolling('5D').sum()})
```

Comment: @maynull And notice that `rolling('5D')` is different from `rolling(5)`.